# How can I pass a variable as an attribute using tags()?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to work with a custom UI, and I would like to pass this output

**server.R**

```
output$myVar <- 10
```

as a value of an attribute (myVar is reactive)

**ui.R**

```
htmlTemplate("index.html",
myVar=tags$div('data-transitiongoal'=myVar))
```

and then call if from the index.html in the classical way

**index.html**

```
{{myVar}}
```

When I deploy the app I get this error:

> ERROR: object 'progressBarPartTimePerc1' not found

However, I substitute a numeric value like `'data-transitiongoal'="20"` the app works just fine.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Not working, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try :
  myVar=tags$div('data-transitiongoal'= as.character(myVar)))